# Using EF 4.1 and LINQ to find unassociated m...n-related entities

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, join, edmx

I have two tables/entities `Users` and `Companies`.
Both are linked m-n relationship.
When I use those tables in my EDMX and generate the POCOs, the m-n mapping table disappears (seemingly becasue there is nothing in there except hte two PKs).

Instead, navigation properties get created by the EDMX, which is fine:

```
user.Companies ... -> gives me all users for that company
```

and

```
company.Users ... -> gives me all companies for that user
```

**But what if I wanted all users that do NOT have a company associated with them?
How would I access the missing table to create the proper join?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find users without company (as you said), so their use.Companies.Count should be zero, just convert this to linq (like what is below):

```
var withoutCompanyUsers = Users.Where(x=>x.Companies.Count() == 0).ToList();
```

**Edit:** About your second problem: But what if I wanted all copmanies that are not associated with the given user?

In this case you should find companies which doesn't have specific user:

Checking company has specific user or not:

```
company.Users.Any(x=>x.ID = givenUserID)
```

Fetching companies without specific user:

```
var companies = Companies.Where(x=>!x.Users.Any(y=>y.ID == givenUser.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting. But what if I wanted all copmanies that are not associated with the given user? I won't find those companies in the x.Companies entity, because those wouldn't be in the mapping table at all.

Comment: @John, you can do: `Companies.Where(x=>!x.Users.Any(y=>y.ID == givenUser.ID);` I'll edit answer to describe your situation.

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't the ! negate any match returned by Any() ? Meaning  that users that are actually assigned would be returned as "not assigned"?

Comment: @John, `Any` checks company has specific user, and `!` checks non of the users of company is `givenUser`, Also you can use: `Companies.Where(x=>x.Users.All(y=>y.ID != givenUser.ID)`

Comment: Thanks again. That seems to work. I actually find the .All() option easier to read. :) While I'm asking dumb quesitons, do you know why the mapping table is not shown in the EDMX?

Comment: @John, I don't know, but simply you can look at related classes, Also you can ask it in different question, and upload image of your edmx image.